# Pass parameter to function using URL

Tags: php, function, url, call

This is the function i tried to call it from url

```
 public function getParentId($childId)
 {
    $statment = $this->db->prepare("SELECT parent FROM `person` WHERE id = $childId");
    $statment->execute();
    $result = $statment->fetchAll();

    foreach($result as $output){

        return $output['parent'];
    }
    echo 'You call the function from url';

 }
```

and i wrote this code to access the function from url

```
 if(isset($_GET['action'])){
    include_once('Family.php');
    $object = new Family;

    switch($_GET['action']){
        case 'getId':
        $object->getParentId($childId);
        break;

        default;
        echo 'There is no function with that name';
        break;
    }
}
```

then i pass the argument from the Url

[test.local/Family.php?action=getId&childId=4](http://test.local/Family.php?action=getId&childId=4)

the output You call the function from url

but he didn't return $output['parent'] why ?

Comment: Try the query direct against the database in PHPMyAdmin to confirm what rows, if any are returned

Comment: Its work ... i call the function from index.php and he returned what i want .

But why its not worked from url call ?

Comment: why you call function with `$childId` instead `$_GET['childId']`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you meant to write the second snippet of code
like this:

```
if(isset($_GET['action'])){
    include_once('Family.php');
    $object = new Family;

    switch($_GET['action']){
        case 'getId':
        $object->getParentId($_GET['childId']); //<= Edit
        break;

        default;
        echo 'There is no function with that name';
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: its not work every thing is gone even the output of echo

Comment: That's because you `return` from your function __before__ `echo`.

Comment: is the link right ? http://test.local/Family.php?action=getId&childId=4

Comment: @u_mulder  I removed the echo its still not displayed any thing

Comment: What should it display? Where do you __output__ function results, huh?

Comment: When i called it from index.php he displayed the echo and the id of parent child. But when i called it from URL he just displayed the echo .. i think there is some problem in  test.local/Family.php?action=getId&childId=4 ???

Comment: Do you __understand__ that function `$object->getParentId()` __outputs nothing__ because you don't have any `echo`, `var_dump`, `print_r` function in it? Do you __understand it__?

Comment: Its work when i added echo after the object ...  echo $object->getParentId($_GET['childId']);